# Unable to connect MAMP server from other machine

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp

I have installed MAMP on my machine(iMac) around 1 year back. Usually I start MAMP server on my iMac & I access the PHP files and all from my iPad/MacBook Pro.

But, recently, I am not able to access the MAMP server from other machine.

Steps I do follow regularly.

1. Drop all my project files in `htdocs` folder.
2. Start MAMP server.
3. Using ip address of my iMac, I will access my application from other machine i.e.,

   `http://192.168.1.32:8888/index.html`
4. Both my iMac & other machines are on same wifi network.

Previously it was working fine. But from one month onwards, its not working.
I am not able to connect to `http://192.168.1.32:8888/index.html`

I have even tried installing MAMP on my MACBOOK PRO too. Even then, same problem.

What could be the reason for this?

Do I have to make any changes in the MAMP application files?

Comment: Check whether you are still using port 8888 for apache in preferences->ports

Comment: Yes nithin. I am using same port. I even tried changing the port. Even then, same problem